# How do I program Python to read bytes from a file as base10 and organize each byte into a list?

Tags: python, unicode, hex, converters, radix

I'm pretty amateur with python and computer data, so bare with me -
I have a file called "input.nodes" and I want to have python read each byte, convert them to base10, and then organize each byte chronologically into a list. I have almost succeeded with this.
I'm using Python 3.10, which if I recall correctly, is the latest version.

To put it even more simply -- How do I make python read each byte as base10, and organize all of them chronologically into a list with NO extra characters whatsoever?

Here's how I attempted to do this:

```
with open('input.nodes') as f:
    dataImport = f.read()

dataImportSplit = [] # << The reason we are adding an empty list is because we will 
                     # sort all of the bytes of the stickfigure into this list.

for chr in dataImport:               # << As stated, this will take all of the bytes
    dataImportSplit.append(ord(chr)) # from input.nodes and sort them into a list.

print('BYTE LIST (in Base10):\n' + str(dataImportSplit)) # << Prints out "dataImportSplit", the
                                                         # list we just sorted bytes into.
                                                         # Just for debugging purposes.
```

To elaborate on this code:

1. Import input.nodes as a string, and let "dataImport" be the variable for it.
2. Create an empty list to later store all of the bytes into, called "dataImportSplit" .
3. Find the Unicode code point of each character in dataImport (via the ord function), and append each of them individually into a list.
4. Print the list into the console as a string for debugging.
   --

That code almost worked; most objects in the list were the base10 representation of the byte and I double-checked with a decimal-to-binary and decimal-to-hex calculator. However, there seemed to be a few outliers that have zero correlation to anything, to my knowledge.

Here is the output in the python terminal:

```
BYTE LIST (in Base10):
[0, 0, 1, 78, 63, 8364, 0, 0, 255, 112, 8250, 68, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 8364, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 31, 31, 31, 255, 127, 127, 127, 255, 127, 127, 127, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 8364, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 45, 255, 112, 8250, 68, 255, 112, 8250, 68, 255, 112, 8250, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Obviously you cant understand what this means if I dont give the actual contents of input.nodes , so for reference, here is input.nodes in a hex editor:
[[image: input.nodes in hex(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zfKV.png)]
[If this is still not enough information, you can download input.nodes for yourself here.](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/854456068196007958/1035734600573517874/input.nodes)

As you can see, the list objects containing '8364' or '8250' dont appear to have any correlation to anything -- no matter what its converted to.

**What am I missing here? What do the numbers "8364" and "8250" have to do with anything?**

Comment: When you open a file without specifying a mode, `'r'` is assumed.  That's a text mode, which means every byte will be decoded into a character using the default encoding.  `8364` is the Euro sign `€` and `8250` is `›`, the [Windows-1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) would produce that result.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the help. If `'r'` will use the default encoding for the euro sign and the greater than symbol, then what mode do I use to stop it from doing that? I tried `'rb'` , but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for; it messed with the other perfectly fine objects in the list.

Comment: If you open in `'rb'` mode you will read byte strings instead of character strings.  You only need to substitute `chr` for `ord(chr)` to make that work.  And I'd choose another variable name instead of `chr` since that's already a Python built-in function; I often use `ch` myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bytes` type in Python represents a sequence of byte-valued integers (0-255), but *displays* by default as an immutable byte string.  If you open your file in binary mode (`'rb'`) the data you read is a byte string that can be accessed as integers individually through indexing or iteration, or you can convert it explicitly to a list.

Opening in text mode (the default) uses an implicit encoding that varies by OS if the `encoding` parameters is not used and *converts* bytes to Unicode code points via that encoding.

If you want the individual bytes, read in binary to prevent any conversion:

```py
with open('downloads\input.nodes', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

print(data[:20])          # displays first 20 bytes as a byte string
print(data[:20].hex(' ')) # hexadecimal dump separated by spaces

for b in data[20:40]: # prints next 20 bytes as integers
    print(b)

print(list(data)) # convert to list
```

Output:

```
b'\x00\x00\x01N?\x80\x00\x00\xffp\x9bD\xff\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
00 00 01 4e 3f 80 00 00 ff 70 9b 44 ff 00 00
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
63
128
0
0
0
0
[0, 0, 1, 78, 63, 128, 0, 0, 255, 112, 155, 68, 255, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 31, 31, 31, 255, 127, 127, 127, 255, 127, 127, 127, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 63, 128, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 45, 0, 0, 0, 45, 255, 112, 155, 68, 255, 112, 155, 68, 255, 112, 155, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```